# Unread notifications count

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the [public_activity gem](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity) to create a list of notifications for users. Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12880066/rails-keeping-count-of-users-unread-notifications) as a reference i'm trying to keep count of the notifications that the user hasn't read. When a user clicks to see the notifications they have, I want the count to go back to zero. The solution to the question above is to create a class method like so:

```
def self.unread
where(:read => false)
end
```

and then put this in the view:

```
user.notifications.unread.update_all(:read => true)
```

My controller looks like this:

```
def notifications
@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").where(recipient_id: current_user.id)
end

def self.unread
where(:read => false)
end
```

and my view looks like this:

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>    
<%= render_activity activity %> 
<% end %>
```

My question is where do i add:

```
.update_all(:read => true)
```

in the view, and how can I get the unread.count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is so easy. You Just have to make its controller-action and call it via ajax when user viewed his notification.

For the shake of example,lets assume how facebook notification will be implemented with this gem.

I will add 2 controller methods

```
def notifications
   @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").where(recipient_id: current_user.id)
   @notification_count = @activities.where(:read => false).count  
end

def read_all_notification
   PublicActivity::Activity.where(recipient_id: current_user.id).update_all(:read => true)
end
```

2 routes

```
get 'some_controller/notifications'
post 'some_controller/read_all_notification'
```

Depending on what `render_activity` renders and where we want to hook this functionality further we can just call the respective `action` via `ajax`. Assuming, i want to hook this functionality which has `some_id` as id. So, i will do like this

```
$(document).on 'click' , '#some_id' , (e)->
    e.preventDefault()
    $.ajax '/some_controller/read_all_notification' ,
        type: "post"
        dataType: "json"
        beforeSend: (xhr) ->
          xhr.setRequestHeader "X-CSRF-Token", $("meta[name=\"csrf-token\"]").attr("content")
        cache: false
```

That all.

It is worth mentioning that `render_activity` takes few other options too which gives full flexibility `how` and `what` you want to render.

Read this https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity/blob/master/lib/public_activity/renderable.rb#L16-L143

This method is the core of `render_activity` method.

Thats all.

Comment: Ok, so first thanks for the answer! A problem though. In the controller 'current_user.notifications' gives an 'undefined method activities' error so I tried this: @notification_count = @activities.where(recipient_id: current_user.id).where(:read => false).count'. But then that gives me this error: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: activities.read: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."recipient_id" = 1 AND "activities"."read" = 'f'

Comment: No, I don't have an activities model. Since i'm using public_activity I didn't think I needed it.

Comment: Ok getting closer :). I added a boolean 'read' to the activities table and @notification_count is passing without errors except it stays at 0 even after I create a new notification.

Comment: BTW, this is what I have in the controller now: @notification_count = @activities.where(:read => false).count

Comment: Any clue why notification_count is still giving me 0 though? <% @notification_count.each do |activity| %> gives me:<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_PublicActivity_Activity:0x0000010c662e90>

Comment: what is the sql generated  when you do  `@activities.where(:read => false).count`

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."recipient_id" = 1 AND "activities"."read" = 'f'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59979/discussion-between-paritosh-piplewar-and-user2759575).

Comment: Hey @ParitoshPiplewar, hate to bother you again but any chance you can explain how I can continue using this link with e.preventDefault() on it. I've looked around but could not find a way.

Comment: can you show me some live example. that will be very helpful

Comment: Sure. The link looks like this: <%= link_to notifications_path(current_user) do %>  <i class="fa fa-bell-o" ></i>  
<% end %>

Comment: sorry, i mean live site where i can check this.

Comment: No, unfortunately only have it running on localhost.

Comment: then i dont think i might able to help you. do one thing, remove `e.preventDefault()` line and test it. i wish it should work

Comment: Ok, that does work. One problem though. When i click on the '.fa fa-bello-o' class it makes (:read => true) before the page even loads so you can't see the new notification. How would I make the notification (:read => true) after I click?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60191/discussion-between-paritosh-piplewar-and-user2759575).

Comment: By the way, you probably want to use a counter_cache - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html